# Emulating C++ string input in C

Tags: c, strings, io

I did the following exercise:

> Write a C program that does the equivalent of C++ `string s; cin>>s;`; that is, define an input operation that reads an arbitrarily long sequence of whitespace-terminated characters into a zero terminated array of chars.

I wonder if it's good code. What could be improved?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct String {
    char* signs;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};

void String_allocate_space(char **c, size_t *capacity)
{
    if (*capacity == 0) {   // allocate the first time
        *capacity = 1;
        *c = malloc(sizeof(**c) * ((*capacity)));
    }
    else {
        *capacity *= 2;     // double the new capacity
        *c = realloc(*c, sizeof(**c) * (*capacity));
    }
    if (*c == NULL)
        exit(-1);
}

void add_character(struct String* string, int ch)
{
    if (string->size == string->capacity) {     // if current letter sz = capacity
        String_allocate_space(&string->signs, &string->capacity);
    }
    string->signs[string->size++] = ch;    // append the sign in the array
}

void String_read(struct String* string)
{
    int ch = ' ';
    while (ch = getc(stdin)) {

        if (!isalpha(ch))
            break;

        add_character(string, ch);
    }
    add_character(string, '\0');
}

void String_print(struct String* string)
{
    printf("%s", string->signs);
}

void String_free(struct String* string)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < string->capacity; ++i) {
        free(string[i].signs);
        string[i].signs = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct String string = { 0 };

    String_read(&string);
    String_print(&string);
    String_free(&string);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This approach consumes the trailing delimiter.  Its value is lost.  Is that truly intended?

Comment: @chux That’s pretty standard behaviour for formatted input in C and C++.

Comment: @KonradRudolph In C, [it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/197218/emulating-c-string-input-in-c?noredirect=1#comment380195_197218) is not.  `scanf("%s", buf)` does not consume trailing white-space after the populating `buf`.  White-space is detected, yet returned to `stdin`.  Similar for `scanf("%d", &i)` and others.

Comment: @chux Fair point. I misremembered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
*c = realloc(*c, sizeof(**c) * (*capacity));
```

Once you have error handling that's more sophisticated than `exit(1)`, this will become a liability.  You need a temporary:

```
char *tmp = realloc(*c, new_capacity);
if (!tmp) {
    /* error handling - c is still valid */
    /* ... */
}
*c = tmp;
*capacity = new_capacity;
```

---

If you always initialize the data pointer to start as a null pointer, you don't need to use `malloc()` instead of `realloc()`.  `String_allocate_space` would be easier to write if it accepts a pointer to a `struct String`; that makes it closer to the object-oriented version:

```
void String_init(struct String* string)
{
    string->data = NULL;
    string->size = string->capacity = 0;
}

void String_allocate_space(struct String* string)
{
    size_t new_capacity = string->capacity ? 2 * string->capacity : 16;
    char *tmp = realloc(string->data, new_capacity);
    if (!tmp) {
        /* error handling - c is still valid */
        exit(1);                /* TODO: improve error reporting */
    }
    string->data = tmp;
    string->capacity = new_capacity;
}
```

I've also incorporated a change above to start with a larger initial size (16) instead of 1.  That lets us skip the first 4 reallocations for free.

---

The `read()` method has a flaw that will become apparent when you try to read another value into a string - unlike `std::string`, reading with `>>` will *append* to it, instead of *replacing* it.  We need to reset `size` at the beginning:

```
void String_read(struct String* string)
{
    string->size = 0;
    int ch;
    while (ch = getc(stdin)) {

        if (!isalpha(ch))
            break;

        add_character(string, ch);
    }
    add_character(string, '\0');
}
```

Also, the logic is slightly wrong - we want to finish when we see a space, rather than any non-alpha (which could be digits or punctuation characters).  (Well done for remembering that `getch()` returns `int` rather than `char` - that's one common error avoided).

```
void String_read(struct String* string)
{
    string->size = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && !isspace(ch)) {
        add_character(string, (char)ch);
    }
    add_character(string, '\0');
}
```

---

When we free the string, we don't need a loop.  Instead, we have a single `free()`.  It's a good idea to reset the `size` and `capacity` so that the string object is consistent - it can be used again and/or freed again without harm:

```
void String_free(struct String* string)
{
    free(string->data);
    string->data = NULL;
    string->size = string->capacity = 0;
}
```

This is an important concept in object-oriented programming - objects have **invariants** that they guarantee are true at the start and end of every (public) operation.  In this case, the invariants are that

- `data` points to valid storage of at least `capacity` if `capacity > 0` and is a null pointer otherwise.
- `size` is not greater than `capacity`.

---

We can improve the printing so that it outputs any embedded NUL characters, just like C++ strings do:

```
void String_print(struct String* string)
{
    if (fwrite(string->data, 1, string->size, stdout) != string->size) {
        exit(1);                /* TODO: improve error reporting */
    }
}
```

Note that this will now print the trailing NUL we added.  We no longer need that to mark the end of string, so we can remove that line.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct String {
    char* data;
    size_t size;
    size_t capacity;
};

void String_init(struct String* string)
{
    string->data = NULL;
    string->size = string->capacity = 0;
}

void String_allocate_space(struct String* string)
{
    size_t new_capacity = string->capacity ? 2 * string->capacity : 1;
    char *tmp = realloc(string->data, new_capacity);
    if (!tmp) {
        /* error handling - c is still valid */
        exit(1);                /* TODO: improve error reporting */
    }
    string->data = tmp;
    string->capacity = new_capacity;
}

void add_character(struct String* string, char ch)
{
    if (string->size == string->capacity) {     // if current letter exceeds capacity
        String_allocate_space(string);
    }
    string->data[string->size++] = ch;    // append it
}

void String_read(struct String* string)
{
    string->size = 0;
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && !isspace(ch)) {
        add_character(string, (char)ch);
    }
}

void String_print(struct String *restrict string, FILE *restrict stream)
{
    if (fwrite(string->data, 1, string->size, stream) != string->size) {
        exit(1);                /* TODO: improve error reporting */
    }
}

void String_free(struct String* string)
{
    free(string->data);
    string->data = NULL;
    string->size = string->capacity = 0;
}

int main()
{
    struct String string;

    String_init(&string);
    String_read(&string);
    String_print(&string, stdout);
    String_free(&string);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the in deep review. i have to admit i didn't even expected to read much comments to this code because i considered the code to easy and short :-) I was quite wrong...   One question i have hwat would be an better error handling? and why `exit(1)` not `exit(-1)`

Comment: One nit to pick.  I would change "if (!tmp)" to "if (tmp == NULL)", because tmp is not a logical (true/false) condition, it's a comparison to a special value, the NULL pointer.  FALSE and NULL just happen to be implemented as 0 in C, but that's not necessarily universally true.

Comment: @jamesqf: That should be "happen to be implemented as 0 in your C implementation". In some implementations (e.g. embedded), `0` is actually a completely valid address.

Comment: @sandro: Positive numbers are the standard convention for exit codes; most shells will truncate/convert to unsigned values - to demonstrate, you can `( exit -1 ); echo $?` in Bash.  So, small positive numbers ensure consistency between what you say you're returning and what your users see.

Comment: @james/hoffmale: It's a standard C (and C++) idiom to test the validity of a pointer by leaving the comparison to `0` implicit.  Remember that a literal `0` always means a null pointer (whether or not the machine uses all-bits-zero for its representation).  `NULL` doesn't "just happen" to be implemented as `0` - the Standard insists that it must be `0`, *even on hardware where the zero address is valid*.  In those cases, the implementation is required to evaluate a pointer holding the zero address as a "true" value.

Comment: Further reading: see the answers to [Does Standard define null pointer constant to have all bits set to zero?](//stackoverflow.com/q/27714377), [Why is address zero used for the null pointer?](//stackoverflow.com/q/2759845) and [Can I use `if (pointer)` instead of `if (pointer != NULL)`?](//stackoverflow.com/17772103).

Comment: Detail: "`0` always means a null pointer" is amiss. `0` is always a constant `int` with value 0.  Comparing that `int` to a pointer `p`, converts the `int` 0 to a _null pointer_.  IAC, `if (!tmp)` is OK, yet as a minor point, I prefer `if (tmp == NULL)` as negations tend to be less clear than positive assertions - don't you not think is won't be otherwise ;-)?  (Good review)

Comment: 3rd link [here] is broken.  Should be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17772103/2410359)

Comment: Thanks @chux (for the link correction (I accidentally deleted the `/a` - oops) and for the comment that's much clearer and more accurate than what I said - yes, it's the *conversion* from `int` that matters, not the literal `0`).

Comment: the corrected code gives errors shouldnt `void String_print(struct String *restrict string, FILE *restrict stream)` be `void String_print(struct String *restrict_string, FILE *restrict_stream)`? why the restrict?

Comment: my other question is `return 0;` in main also optional in c? I thought it only gets compiler generated in c++

Comment: Also in the `String_read` method you dont initalize `ch`. I know it gets initalized directly in the next statement `while (ch = getc(stdin) != EOF && !isspace(ch)) `. However on my compiler (visual studio 2017) it terminates the programm with "Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 'ch' is being used without being initialized."

Comment: @Toby Speight: It may be a "standard" idiom, at least among those who like to obfuscate their code, but that does not make it any less a source of potential confusion.

Answer (score 10):

Since @TobySpeight has already posted a wonderful answer, I'm not going to repeat what he has already posted.

Just some small additional notes:

- `String_allocate_space` allocates 1 `char`s worth of memory if the `capacity` is 0. This is barely enough to hold the terminating `'\0'` character, but nothing more. Maybe increase the default minimal allocation size a bit to be meaningful?
- Also, regarding naming: If I see a function called `String_free`, I'd expect a function `String_alloc` that allocates and creates the `String` object in a well-defined state. (And consequently, `String_free` should then deallocate that `String` correctly.)

Also, this might just be me, but from the task description I'd expect the solution to be a `char *read_input(void)` function. While the `String` "class" is nice, it seems like a bit of over-engineering for the task at hand.

For comparison, look at this solution:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define INITIAL_INPUT_CAPACITY 4

char *read_input(void) {
    size_t capacity = INITIAL_INPUT_CAPACITY;
    size_t size = 0;
    char *str = malloc(capacity * sizeof(char));
    int input;

    while((input = getc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        if(isspace(input)) break;

        str[size++] = (char)input;

        if(size == capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
            char *temp = realloc(str, capacity * sizeof(char));

            if(temp == NULL) {
                exit(-1);
            }

            str = temp;
        }
    }

    str[size++] = '\0';

    return str;
}

int main(void) {
    char *input = read_input();
    puts(input);
    free(input);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was continuing my answer as you wrote this.  I didn't think of the better initial capacity, though.

Comment: i think this code reflects more the ximplicity of c. since i do mostly c++ i think i tend to overengineer "easy" tasks

Comment: @Sandro4912: I don't think this is about "simplicity of C". C programs can very easily become very complex, even more complex than C++ with classes and templates. This is about using the right tool for the job, adhering to general language idioms and not doing more than what is needed.